# Typescript function generic arguments in function variable `Cannot find name 'React'`

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

How to write this typescript function with generic arguments in a variable function(store the function in a variable)?

```
function identity<T>(arg: T): T {
  return arg;
}
```

I tried this and it complains `Cannot find name 'React'`

```
const identity = <T>(arg: T): T => {
    return arg;
}
```

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're referring to the `Cannot find name 'React'.` error, that's because typescript tries to parse `<T>..` as a React element. You can add a comma after the generic parameter to prevent this: `<T>` ~> `<T,>`

```
const identity = <T,>(arg: T): T => {
  return arg;
}
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlgEwKZinKBPGBeGAeAFQBoA%20ACgEMAnAcwC4YCBKBgnEmAbwCgYYqkUAK5UwMajQDc3AL7cgA)

Alternatively, you can add a dummy extends clause, e.g. `<T extends {}>`, but `<T,>` is the cleanest solution.